# Understanding Proper Structure of a Node Application

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how best to architect my app.  But for starters trying to understand typical practices with respect to where to put things, and how the app should wire up to things like server.js, how server.js should work, and how you keep a persistent connection open for the website, and any backend services or modules.

This is a general question but let me try to be more specific, as specific as I can since I am new to Node.. and for a basis to start on with this question.

Lets say I plan on designing a simple Express App.

I've got this kind of structure for example so far:

[image]

Right now in **server.js**, I am just playing around with trying to connect to a mySQL database.  So I've got a connection pool I'm creating, one call to the store to retrieve data, requires at the time for the node-mysql middleware I'm using, etc.

**app.js** just has very simple code, it's not modular yet, or even production ready but that's just me playing with the code, spiking things out.  So in it I have you're typical stuff like setting the view, var app = express();, importing an express route definition from another module in my routes\index.js, stuff like that.

if I'm going to keep a database connection open, or other things open, how is that best organized/done by convention?

If you look at this example code, he's moving the var app = express() definition into service.js: https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/server.js.  He keeps an open connection running and started from there, which makes sense, hence "server".

so should app.js do much?  what is best practice or scope of what this should be doing.  Once I start modularizing things out into their own .js files and node modules, how does the app.js morph through all those refactorings, meaning in the end what's its role and is it very thin in the end where it's just used to wire stuff up?

Then what should **www.js** which is now required by express 4 have and it's role?

It's kinda hard for me to start with just one aspect so I'm kinda going all over the place here in the above.  I just want to know common conventions for putting stuff in app.js vs. server.js and then best way to keep and managed open connections to things...both in the backend and front-end such as http requests coming in, what should be the central point?  routes of course but then so is app.js responsible for referencing routes?

I have found a few resources such as [this](http://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html) but looking for more so if you know any or have any input, please reply.  I'm more interested in the talk around app.js, server.js, connections, www.js, and where things should wire up to each other with these particular specific parts.  I realize the rest is up to you on how you wanna name folders, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, when it comes to structuring your application, we're still in the wild west in that there is no "best practice" or structure that is "best" all round. It depends on the needs and size of your project.

Comment: How does app.js and server.js differ in your case? and www.js? seems to me like they would be redundant.

Comment: I usually store my connection in a standalone module under a `lib` folder. It simply requires in the db driver, a config file, creates a connection pool, and exports that pool. Then, anything that needs to access the db simply requires that module. In my case that file connects to mongodb through mongoose. My smtp mailer is handled the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right way and (arguably) no wrong way. There are which are better than others, but then someone might say that they don't like this way and you should do it the other way and so on, until your project is over the deadline.

I often refer to [this blog post](http://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html) about best practices when developing an express app.

You could also try one of [yeoman generators](http://yeoman.io/generators/). Choose one that suits most/all of your needs.

Bottom line, there is sadly still no answer to best structure of an app, I would recommend you to pick something that works best for you (and your team) and stick with it. Consistency is the most important thing to keep in mind while developing and JavaScript community it clearly lacking it.

Comment: Everyone knows there is no "right" way but there are "better" ways that have already been established.  But thanks for the references